# Generating pdf documents with geometries and raster using python

Tags: python, gdal, pyqgis, ogr, pyqt

I'm looking for a way to generate PDF document containing:
1. Text in specified position 
2. Raster file with border 
3. Geometries overlaying raster. 
Basically it should look like this 
 [image]

Geometries and title are stored in postgis db. Raster file is stored somewhere on my server. I could creat qgis project and use it's libraries to do that but it takes a lot of time to open qgis and generate pdf. My question is: Is it possible to generate pdf with those components using just ogr and gdal ? or maybe there is better solution.

Comment: For qgis you have this plugin https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/GeorefExport/ and if you use a cmd ,you can look this repo,I have some examples https://github.com/All4Gis/GeoPdfGdal